# Can I change the Multitasking view icon style?

Tags: design, multitasking-view

When I click Multitasking View I get this icon at the bottom:

[image]

Can I set them up to appear bigger, something like this:

[image]

So that I can see exactly what there is?

This becomes a bigger problem when I have 5+ apps open. Can I change it?

Comment: Are you just using 1 workspace?

Comment: @LewisGoddard At that point in time, yes. Lemme upload full screen image. http://i.stack.imgur.com/FkPmQ.png

Comment: Just for those occasions, using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> may be more suited.

Comment: @LewisGoddard Ahh, nice idea. Will use that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, currently you cannot change these icons' size - they are adjusted automatically. However, if you're interested in this feature, you might consider to open a bug report on launchpad. The Multitasking View is part of [Gala](https://launchpad.net/gala), the window manager used by elementary OS.

Comment: [Reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1472804) :)

Comment: Great, hopefully a developer is interested in working on it soon :)